# Error log for Octave "panic: Illegal instruction -- stopping myself"

Tags: octave

Is there an error log where I can figure out the error message and line of code in my file which makes the Octave interpreter post the following messages in Emacs?

```
panic: Illegal instruction -- stopping myself...
panic: attempted clean up apparently failed -- aborting...

Process Inferior Octave aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the Octave debugger (take a look at the [Debugging section](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Debugging.html) of the Octave manual).

If this was an error message, you could activate `debug_on_error`. Since it is not, it's a proper crash, you must start on debug mode (enter the `keyboard` command) and step line by line (enter the command `dbstep`) until you find which one causes the issue.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I had to do yesterday and found out that I need to install some blas and atlas packages